# Django Admin - Create 'temporary' entry

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way to make it so the Django Admin panel creates a temporary model when you click the "add" button?

I want to be able to 'attach' **multiple** files / media to a particular model entry which would involve uploading the files at the time of creation. I can't do this until the model has a pk as obviously I can't create a link between the uploaded file and the entry.

I am using the Content-Type framework to create the attachment between my uploaded file (which is wrapped in a class)

I noticed that Wordpress for example creates what is called an 'auto draft' when you click the "new post" button to get around problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to take care that the filename of your uploaded file corresponds with the model's PK where the file-fields are used.

There is nothing you must change in the django-admin, but make some adjustions on your model:

First, make use of ["upload_to"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) in your filefield. I usually set the filename to a [uuid4-value](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html) to make sure it's unique.

After saving the model, you can rename the file if you want. The best place is in a function that is triggered by a [post-save-signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save). But if you only want to ensure, that the filename is unique, the filename-generation by uuid should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not really what I was after, the filename of the file is irrelevant, I want to create an attachment using a GenericKey and the ContentTypes framework. I'll update my post to make it clearer.